# How to Integrate Leaflet with Mapbox GL In vuejs

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, mapbox-gl

I am trying to integrate Leaflet in mapbox GL so we can use mapbox GL map and draw shapes using leaflet.

I have tried this code and want to add leaflet into this.

```
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer" class="basemap"></div>
</template>

<script>
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

export default {
  name: "BaseMap",
  data() {
    return {
      accessToken: MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = this.accessToken;

    new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "mapContainer",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [103.811279, 1.345399],
      zoom: 12,
      maxBounds: [
        [103.6, 1.1704753],
        [104.1, 1.4754753],
      ],
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have to used Leaflet with Mapbox GL in Vue.js Then used following step

Step 1: Install the Leaflet packages in your project

```js
npm install mapbox-gl
npm i -D @vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet leaflet
```

Step 2: Then Create the GoogleMap.vue commponet file

```js
<script>
    import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
    import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

    export default {
      components: {
        LMap,
        LTileLayer,
      },
      mounted() {
        this.initMap();
      },
      methods: {
        initMap() {
          const map = L.map(this.$refs.map).setView([YOUR_INITIAL_LATITUDE, YOUR_INITIAL_LONGITUDE], YOUR_INITIAL_ZOOM_LEVEL);

          L.tileLayer(
            "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}",
            {
              maxZoom: 12,
              tileSize: 300,
              zoomOffset: -1,
              accessToken: 'here token code',
            }
          ).addTo(map);
        },
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style>
    .map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    </style>

    <template>
      <div id="map">
        <div ref="map" class="map"></div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Step 3: Then Import the GoogleMap.vue component in Your main component

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to integrate Leaflet into MapboxGl.

```js
<template>
  <LMap id="map" :center="center" :zoom="zoom">
    <LTileLayer
      :options="layerOptions"
      :tile-layer-class="tileLayerClass" />
  </LMap>
</template>

<script>
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from 'vue2-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
import 'mapbox-gl-leaflet'
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
window.mapboxgl = mapboxgl // mapbox-gl-leaflet expects this to be global
export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer
  },
  data () {
    return {
      center: [39.9523893, -75.1636291],
      zoom: 14,
      tileLayerClass: (url, options) => L.mapboxGL(options),
      layerOptions: {
        accessToken: 'no-token',
        style: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/osm2vectortiles/mapbox-gl-styles/master/styles/bright-v9-cdn.json'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#map {
  height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<template>
  <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Map',
  mounted() {
    // Initialize Leaflet map
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([YOUR_LATITUDE, YOUR_LONGITUDE], YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL);

    // Add Mapbox GL layer to Leaflet map
    const mapboxAccessToken = 'YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    L.mapboxGL({
      accessToken: mapboxAccessToken,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // You can use your desired Mapbox style here
    }).addTo(this.map);
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?